# How to compare particular element in list python3?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, iteration, break

```
    l1= [['1', 'apple', '1', '2', '1', '0', '0', '0'], ['1', 
              'cherry', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0']]
    
    l2 = [['1', 'cherry', '2', '1'], 
    ['1', 'plums', '2', '15'], 
    ['1', 'orange', '2', '15'], 
    ['1', 'cherry', '2', '1'], 
    ['1', 'cherry', '2', '1']]
    output = []
    for i in l1:
        for j in l2:
            if i[1] != j[1]:
                output.append(j)
        break
    print(output)
    
    Expected Output:
        [['1', 'plums', '2', '15'], ['1', 'orange', '2', '15']]
```

How to stop iteration and find unique elements and get the sublist?
How to stop iteration and find unique elements and get the sublist?

Comment: You want elements in l2 that are not in l1 ?

Comment: yes want only in l2 @Mike67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the elements in L2 that are not in L1 based on the fruit name:

```
l1= [[1,'apple',3],[1,'cherry',4]]
l2 = [[1,'apple',3],[1,'plums',4],[1,'orange',3],[1,'apple',4]]
output = []
for e in l2:
   if not e[1] in [f[1] for f in l1]:  # search by matching fruit
       output.append(e)

print(output)
```

Output

```
[[1, 'plums', 4], [1, 'orange', 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the unique elements from `list1` in a new list, then check for list2 if that element exists in the `new list`. Something like:

```
newlist = []
for item in l1:
    if item[1] not in newlist:
        newlist.append(item)
output = []
for item in l2:
    if item[1] not in newlist:
        output.append(item)
print(output)
```

This is slightly inefficient but really straightforward to understand.